# clicking next button on reddit with selenium not doing anything

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
private void next() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By
                .xpath("//span[contains(.,'next')]"));
        element.click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

is this code correct, all that happens when next is clicked is the focus scrolls down the page to the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your xpath selector is wrong.

Change it to:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By
    .xpath("//a[contains(text(),'next')]"));
```

or even better (in case one of the topic links contains the text "next") use:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By
    .xpath("//span[@class='nextprev']/a[contains(text(), 'next')]"));
```

This will ensure that the a element that is picked up is within the correct span at the bottom of the page and make your test less brittle.

Answer (score 1):

The `xpath = //span[contains(.,'next')]`  used in your code, locates span with contents `view more : next ›` ,but you need to click only on `next ›`.i.e., you need to click on the anchor tag which contains `next ›`.

The below code will solve the issue.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By
                    .linkText("next ›"));
            element.click();
            System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to avoid xpath and use other locators like linkText or partialLinkText in this case.